# Inequality of expectation of a quadratic form

Tags: probability, quadratic-forms

I was reading a proof in a paper. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two possibly correlated $K$-dimensional random vectors. Suppose $\mathrm{E}(YY^T)=I$, where $I$ is an $K\times K$ identity matrix. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have $\left\{\mathrm{E}(X^TY)\right\}^2 \leq \mathrm{E}(X^TX)\mathrm{E}(Y^TY)$, and $\mathrm{E}(Y^TY)$ here equals to $K$. Beyond this, the author claims the following inequality:
$$
\mathrm{E}\left\{(X^TY)^2\right\} \leq \mathrm{E}(X^TX)\mathrm{E}(Y^TY).
$$
I don't see the reason as in general we have only $\mathrm{E}\left\{(X^TY)^2\right\} \geq \left\{\mathrm{E}(X^TY)\right\}^2$. This claim is analogous to the quadratic form as we can write $\mathrm{E}\left\{(X^TY)^2\right\}=\mathrm{E}\left\{(X^TYY^TX)\right\}$. When $YY^T$ is constant, it is easy
$$
\mathrm{E}\left\{X^TAX\right\} \leq \lambda_\max(A)\mathrm{E}(X^TX),
$$
where $\lambda_\max(A)$ is the greatest eigenvalue of $A$ (we also have the formula for $\operatorname{E}\left\{X^TAX\right\}$ in terms of the trace of $A\operatorname{var}(X)$). Is this claim right? How to show it?

Comment: I've deleted my answer; I will probably drastically edit it and then reinstate it.

Comment: I saw your earlier answer. Thanks, but I agree with @AlexanderVigodner. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two binary random variables, taking values from $1$ and $0$. So $X^2$ and $Y^2$ have the same distributions as $X$ and $Y$ have. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are positive correlated. Then $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)>0$, equivalently $E(X^2 Y^2) - E(X^2)E(Y^2)>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't even work for scalar random variables. For example, if $X=Y$ then the proposed inequality reads $$\mathbb{E}(X^4)\leq [\mathbb{E}(X^2)]^2.$$ 
Subtracting gives 
$$\mbox{Var}(X^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^4)-[\mathbb{E}(X^2)]^2\leq 0,$$
which can only happen if $X^2$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: Yes, the only case where $\leqslant$ holds is when $X^2$ is almost surely constant, and then $=$ holds.

Comment: @Did Yes, thanks for this observation. It makes the result even clearer. I've rewritten my answer to incorporate your comment.